# Pre-populated edit summary refers to previous edit

Tags: bug

I edited the title of [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43802474/latest-nugets-for-outlook-rest-api), saved (without entering an edit summary), then edited again to modify the content.  Whilst the form was submitting (too late to change it), I noticed that the edit summary for the content change was now pre-populated with "edited title".  While formulating this Meta question, I edited a couple more times and saw the same thing.  Then on a third edit it reverted to being a blank edit summary.

If it were me, I would write some JQuery to look for changes to both title and content, and using that, pre-populate the edit summary (if blank) based on the *current* edit, not previous edits.

Comment: Search the help center and this meta site for "grace period" and you'll understand this behaviour.

Comment: If you want to change the summary without changing the content (within the grace period), enter some dummy character on the content.